# Opencart Error No: 1054 when moving servers

Tags: php, opencart

I am moving an installation of Opencart from one server to another and I am getting an error:

```
Error: Unknown column 'store_id' in 'where clause'
Error No: 1054
SELECT * FROM setting WHERE store_id = '0' OR store_id = '0' ORDER BY store_id ASC
```

I put the installation on the local instance to test and everything works fine however when I move it to the server I get the above. There is not an update to the software and all DB/paths are correct as I have another opencart installation which was moved at the same time and that one works.

I have checked that store_id exists in setting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the table hasn't copied over correctly, or you're using a more up to date version of OpenCart with an older version of a database. Try to re-upload your `setting` table from your local working version

Comment: Table copied over correctly. I tried 3 times 1 with the original dump and twice with the local version. I am using the same version DB as my local however my PHP on the server. Locally I am using PHP 5.4.8 and on the server 5.4.14. Will that matter considering the other migration works?

Comment: Highly unlikely to be honest. If you run `EXPLAIN setting` via console/PHPMyAdmin what does it show for both tables (add to your original question if they differ). The only other thing I can think of is that the DB credentials are wrong and you're using an incorrect database to the one you think you are

Comment: Both were the same but you were right. For some reason when the migration happened the site that wasn't working was trying to connect to the DB of the site that was working...sorry for wasting you time

Comment: Ah. You need to edit your `config.php` and `admin/config.php` when moving server to reflect the DB change

Comment: I did do that however because I was moving two installations on the second installation update I uploaded that file to the first installations directory. My fault for doing to migrations at once

Comment: Ah I see. We all do it :-)